# Parse + Facebook Questions

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am trying to implement Parse + Facebook

Here is what I would like to do:

1. User Log In with Facebook
2. Login Authorized
3. **A new User created from Facebook properties (gender, age, name, etc)**

Below is my code which logs in to Facebook using `PFFacebookUtils`. The code successfully created a User on my Parse, **but I don't have those details of the User from Facebook which I want to use**.

I would like to get the user's name, gender, hometown, etc on Facebook.

How do I achieve that??

```
    var permissionArray = ["public_profile","user_friends","email","user_birthday", "user_work_history", "user_education_history", "user_hometown", "user_location", "user_likes"]; on Facebook

        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionArray) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                if user!.isNew {
                    println("New User");
                }
                else {
                    println("Old  User");
                }
                println(user?.username);
            }
            else {
                println("Login Cancel")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the users "me" data, and then you can use that to populate your user object. So, in your `if user!.isNew {` you'll need to do something along the lines of...

```
let fbDetailsRequest = FBRequest.requestForMe()
fbDetailsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { connection, result, error in
  if error != nil {
    // Handle the error
  }

  if let graph = result as? FBGraphObject {
    // Now you can fill out the data on your user object
    user!.setObject(graph.objectForKey("email")!, forKey: "email")
    user!.setObject(graph.objectForKey("gender")!, forKey: "gender")
    // Don't forget to save afterwards...
    user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
  }
}
```

To see the fields you can grab, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user If you need anything other than "core" items, you might have to have extra permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the FBRequest class is already deprecated